# gino.exceptions.UninitializedError: Gino engine is not initialized

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, gino

I've created a telegram bot with gino. When I start this bot on my computer everything work fine. But when I try to start it on AWS server, I get this error: gino.exceptions.UninitializedError: Gino engine is not initialized.

The error in this part of code:

```
request = await Info.query.where(Info.id == user_id).gino.all()
```

Could you tell me, why I have this problem in the server, if I don't have any problems when I start this bot on my computer? And how can I solve this problem?